# Warlock Eldritch master good for nothing?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

I find the Warlock level 20 feature **Eldritch Master** totally useless as it states:

> **Eldritch Master:** At 20th level, you can draw on your inner reserve of
>   mystical power while entreating your patron to regain
>   expended spell slots. You can spend 1 minute entreating
>   your patron for aid to regain all your expended spell slots
>   from your Pact Magic feature. Once you regain spell slots
>   with this feature, you must finish a long rest before you
>   can do so again.

But your spell slots are always recharged on a short rest.

> **Spell Slots:** The Warlock table shows how many spell slots you have.
>   The table also shows what the level of those slots is; all
>   of your spell slots are the same level. To cast one of your
>   warlock spells of 1st level or higher, you must expend a
>   spell slot. ***You regain all expended spell slots when you
>   finish a short or long rest***.

So, what's the point of **Eldritch Master**? I thought that maybe an errata and the recharged slots are the ones from **Mystic Arcanum**, that would be a good 20th level feature.

We are using a short rest variant that makes short rests 5-10 minutes instead of an hour.

Comment: I think your DM giving your 5-10 minute short rests is doing a dis-service to your group. The game mechanics are written to make a short rest more available than a long rest, but still...It's a rest that you regain certain abilities, functions and can even heal _some_ hit points back. You can't really justify this happening within 5 minutes unless you are using a healing potion and mana potion mechanic and just giving the characters time to empty a draught or two of each.

Comment: It is not the ability's fault that your DM adapted a short rest variant. yes, this is 9 years old, but a lot of folks have come up with ways to change the short rest both mechanically and narratively. (I have 1 DM who makes the first one 30 minutes, the second one 60 minutes. There are other adaptations as well.  Would suggest taking a look at them if you are still playing.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast notably, I believe there is a Gritty variant wherein short is nightly and long is weekly.

Comment: Yes; the ones in this question go in the opposite direction from the DMG variants.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Short rests require an hour in which

> a character does nothing more strenuous than eating, drinking, reading, and tending to wounds.

(PHB, page 186.)

Eldritch Master takes one minute, and doesn't specify what you can and can't be doing in that time. It's unclear (i.e. open to DM ruling) if you have to spend that minute doing nothing except entreating your patron, but even if that's true, sometimes, you don't have an hour. If you're running away from something, you might just be able to get a minute lead on it to quickly get your spells back. An hour lead is a lot less likely.

A minute is a *very* short time out of combat, and even in combat, it's 10 rounds. In a protracted fight you could probably pull this off. In a *really* protracted fight, you might need to. For example, if you're fighting the Tarrasque, your Eldritch Blast will be entirely useless. Once you're out of spell slots, you're going to be standing around doing nothing. (Slight exaggeration.) Your allies might be able to keep you alive for 10 rounds so that you can get some spells which have a chance of achieving something.

It shouldn't need pointing out, but an hour is 600 rounds, which is just not going to be possible in any combat. (Unless you're fighting a Dire Half-Dragon Fiendish *Snail* or something, but that's just getting silly.)

Of course, all of this is somewhat pointless if your DM is ok with you doing other things during the minute it takes to use this. For example, even if you're only allowed to use your movement, running around for a minute screaming at your patron for help seems completely achievable. If your DM rules that you can fight as normal during that minute, then this feature might actually be *too* powerful. Get into a fight with a tough enemy? Start praying to your patron. That gives you 10 rounds to use all your resources, at the end of which you just get them back immediately. Personally, I wouldn't be quite *that* lenient, but that's up to your DM.

Comment: Great answer, the problem is that we were using short rest of 5-10 minutes, so the 1 minute thing seemed poor difference for a 20th level feature.

Comment: @CorvenDallas I'd ask your DM to allow this power to be instant out of combat then. It's not a combat power (10 rounds is a long time to sit idle), but with your short rest variant, making it much quicker is legit.

Comment: Yeah, if we use lesser short rest times, maybe the ability should reduce time accordingly. We will see.

Comment: (+1), if only for the Dire Half-Dragon Fiendish Snail.  Though would be even better if there were three of them, in a trenchcoat.

Answer (score 28):

The point of Eldritch Master is to give you the benefit of a Short Rest in a much shorter time (1 minute instead of 60).

From your clarification in response to the first answer, your group is using a variant of Short Rest as 5-10 minutes, rather than 60. This greatly reduces the power of Eldritch Master, as it's now speeding up recovery by 5-10x rather than 60x, and if your group is regarding Short Rest as a thing that happens all the time (which is what a 5-10 minute break suggests to me), then *in your case* Eldritch Master isn't useful.

RAW, however, it's a useful if not awesome ability.

Answer (score -7):

It is a bottom-shelf ability and one of the weakest capstones there is, but with your party's short rest variant it's absolutely worthless. For Eldritch master to keep its power, your DM should be shorten it to one action. That is a fair trade during combat.

Comment: Answer needs to clean up the language and be more than an opinion.  The [tour], the [help], [ask] and [answer] offer guidance on how to best respond to questions on this site.  This isnt' redit, this isn't a forum, this isn't Twitter_X, this isn't a chat room.  Beyond that, Welcome to RPGSE. 