# Eldritch Master Clarification

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, spell-slots

20th-level warlocks get the [Eldritch Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#EldritchMaster) feature, which lets them spend a minute asking their patron to regain expended spell slots (from the Pact Magic feature), and ends with this the statement:

> Once you regain spell slots with this feature, you must finish a long rest before you can do so again.

I first interpreted this to mean that after using Eldritch Master, you have to take a long rest to regain spell slots the next time. Basically like there's a downside to using the ability.

Recently, I've wondered if I'm misinterpreting this and it means that you simply can only spend the 1 minute of "entreating your patron for aid" to regain expended spell slots once per long rest, but that spell slots are always regained on a short rest as normal (other than when using Eldritch Master of course).

Can any D&D legal scholars help me interpret this vague language?

Comment: Not sure if this is a dupe or not, but I think https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57180/warlock-eldritch-master-good-for-nothing addresses this issue by covering in some detail how EM works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warlock Eldritch master good for nothing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57180/warlock-eldritch-master-good-for-nothing)

Comment: It's a different question, and stems from a misreading of the words. The other questions asks what value it has, this one is confusing regaining spell slots in the normal fashion, and "regaining using this feature" once per long rest. Both can happen between long rests. The feature allows a separate regaining once per long rest.

Comment: This is definitely not a dupe. The answers for both questions cover basically the same ground, but that's not what determines a dupe, it's whether the _questions_ are asking the same thing that determines if a question is a dupe. This question asks for a clarification on wording for recharge, the other asks what the ability does at all. Related questions, but not duplicates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is the capstone Warlock ability, it has no downside. What it specifically allows you to do, is sans a short rest, spend a minute (as opposed to an hour for a short rest), to regain spell slots. After you have done this, you can still spend short rests to regain spell slots, but you will not be able to use this ability again, until you take a long rest.

Comment: +1 for referencing the fact that it's a capstone ability - For a L20 ability to have a downside I'd want the upside to be pretty darned ridiculous!